# iOS 10, XCode 8 Black camera screen when using ABPersonViewController and CNContactViewController

Tags: ios, ios-camera, abpersonviewcontroller, cncontactviewcontroller

Using xcode 8, devices using iOS 9 and 10

I've got same problems like [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19551)

Camera does not working with ABPersonViewController and CNContactViewController.

It pops up with black screen and non of contained controls are working except cancel button.

I've searched several questions, but didn't help.

any clues.
Thanks.

ps. Already added NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSContactsUsageDescription to info.plist file.

Comment: Go to the Settings page for your app in the Settings app. Is camera access disabled?

Comment: @rmaddy nope. All access options are enabled.

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem.  In fact, my app explicitly DOES have permission to use the camera.  But if we get to it from ABPersonViewController, it behaves exactly as if permission for the camera has been disabled.

Comment: @Ahn - Have you fixed the camera issue of CNContactViewController because I am facing the same. Let me know the solution if it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Noticed that 'Take Photo' is not appearing in iOS 11 version, Apple might have removed it as its bug. I did not find an Apple link for official confirmation on this.